# Functions are not available in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on [Arrow](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow) project and I'm in phase to create the **Bundle** file using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

I grouped my [modules](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/tree/master/src/1.x.x/scripts/array) in a folder. and for each folder I have [index.js](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/tree/master/src/1.x.x/scripts/array/has) where I export all modules.

Also, I have global [index.js](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/blob/master/src/1.x.x/index.js) that imports all **index.js** like this :

```
import * as Has from "./scripts/array/has"
import * as  Math from "./scripts/array/math"
import * as  Arrow from "./scripts/array"
export { Has, Math, Arrow }
```

Now, I want to create my bundle from this global [index.js](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/blob/master/src/1.x.x/index.js) .

My [Webpack](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/blob/master/webpack.config.js) configuration looks like :

```
const path = require("path")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        arrow: "./src/1.x.x/index",
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build',
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name]-alpha.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
        },
    },
}
```

The **Issue** is when I try to import my functions from the [build](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/tree/master/build) the functions do not appear in the **Autocomplete** and I received errors that these functions are `undefined`!

I have just `___esModule` :

```
import { __esModule } from "./arrow-alpha"
```

I want to let developers use and import the functions like the [example](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow#basic-example)

```
import {omit} from "arrow" // arrow is the bundled file

const frameworks = ["react", "vue", "ember", "angular"];
const withoutAngular = omit(frameworks,"angular");

console.log(withoutAngular); // ["react", "vue", "ember"]
```

I blocked in this step for days and I could not figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking to export your code as library with `webpack`. In order to do so, you should export your library module as `umd` which can work for backend/client side so IDE can also understand what you export. Just add following configuration in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
output: {
  libraryTarget: 'umd', // style for your library
  library: 'yourLibName', // if you keen to have a name for library
  // ...
},
```

***NOTE***: this only works if you pass to `webpack` a `cjs` style code, otherwise it will convert to harmony module which you can't export accordingly (such as `esm` module)

In order to make sure `babel` would convert your `esm` module to `commonjs`, you have to set `modules` to `commonjs` like this:

`babel.config.js` or `.babelrc`

```
[
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    "modules": "commonjs",
  }
]
```

Comment: I still receiving only `__esModule`.

Comment: You can check the links in the post. This is the bundle file : [bundle](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow/tree/master/build)

Comment: It seems you haven't run build again. Can you try to build again?

Comment: I generated the new bundle, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Ah I see. It looks like if you input as `esm` to `webpack`, it would create to `harmony` module which IDE doesn't understand. But if you use `babel` to convert `cjs` first, then pass to `webpack` then it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221166/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-menai-ala-eddine-aladdin).

Comment: Don't miss to edit the answer based on the discussion. `Babel Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below Configuration. Will eject your final bundle to be accessed as **Window.Arrow** on adding script to index.html page

```
output: {
        filename: "[name]-alpha.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        library: 'Arrow',
        libraryTarget: 'var'
    },
```

and your index.js page inside src folder to be as

```
module.exports = require('./scripts/array');
```

Comment: I tried but I could not access them. Would you open a PR? [open pull request](https://github.com/MenaiAla/arrow)